# How can I make the code recognize "page not available" of an Instagram profile?

Tags: python, instagram

I am writing a code that returns Instagram's page weblink if page exists.

I have the following lines:

```
if response.status_code == 200:

            return profile_url
```

The problem is that it cannot recognize "page not available" results for when username does not exist because this page returns the same code as a working page - 200.

**How can I make the code recognize "page not available"?** (it would be easy if it returned 404 status code but it returns 200)

I tried using ensta library but it was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Instagram returns a status code of 200 even when the page doesn't exist, you may need to rely on the content of the response to determine whether the page is available.

Here's an example of code:

```
if "Page Not Found" in response.text:
        print("Page not available")
        return None
    elif response.status_code == 200:
        return profile_url
```